# Как сделать аналог ангулярского RouterOutlet в Blazor?

Tags: .net, blazor

В общем, в `Angular` есть такая штука, как `RouterOutlet`, которая позволяет автоматически в зависимости от маршрута перерисовывать область компонентом, который отвечает за этот маршрут.

Такой фичи в Blazor я не нашел...

А как что-то подобное можно сделать в `Blazor`? Нужно через аякс запросы перерисовывать куски?

Answer (score 0):

Для этой цели вы можете сделать проcто шэред компонент и использовать в нем NavigationManager:

```
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager;
<h3>Текущий путь: @currentRoute</h3>

@code {
    protected string currentRoute;

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        currentRoute = navigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(navigationManager.Uri);
    }

}
```

Comment: По моему это не совсем чистое решение. А если у меня внутри одного компонента другой компонент, который тоже внутри рендерит свое содержимое в зависимости от маршрута?